# Cross compare data between 2 workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, comparison, highlighting

I'm trying to cross compare 2 data in 2 different workbook. Then, I need to find the missing data between the 2 and make a separate new, updated list. However, I only need to update the data if there's a record from the first list. If not, there isn't a need to update that data.

E.G

```
Workbook 1
ID            Name      Code
...
futa-123456   Max       0a
futa-123458   Max       0a   
futb-ms8793   John      SX
futg-809153   May       gH
...

Workbook 2
ID            Name      Contact Address Code Flag
...
futa-123456   Max       ...       ...    0a   Y
futa-123457   Max       ...       ...    0a   Y
futb-XY5543   Sam       ...       ...    SX   N
futg-809153   May       ...       ...    gH   Y
futg-809154   May       ...       ...    gH   Y
... 

Final Result
Separate new sheet (doesn't natter which workbook)
ID            Name      Code
...
futa-123456   Max       0a
futa-123457   Max       0a* 
futa-123458   Max       0a   
futb-ms8793   John      SX
futg-809153   May       gH
futg-809154   May       gH*
...
```

So, excel will show the differences on both sides of the workbook for Max because there are differences between both sides and they are present in workbook 1. For May, only workbook 2 will show the differences since only workbook 2 has the differences(but will still show since May is present in workbook 1). Sam will not be highlighted because workbook 1 doesn't have Sam.

Basically, I'm cross comparing with Workbook 1 as the source. If there isn't a record in workbook 1 but is present in Workbook 2, it won't be highlighted.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please edit the Final result for better understanding.

Comment: Can't seemed to bold the changes so I added a * at the end. Let me know if it's still unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps required to do this manually are quite long and tedious.

Assuming that the data in Workbook 1 is in `Sheet1` follow these steps:

1. Copy the data (including headers) from Workbook 2
2. Paste into cell `A1` of an empty worksheet in Workbook 1 (say `Sheet2`)
3. Enter this formula into `G1` → `=MATCH(B1,Sheet1!B:B,0)`
4. Copy-paste or fill the formula down appropriately. I prefer this keystroke sequence:

   - <kbd>Left</kbd>
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>
   - <kbd>Right</kbd>
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>
   - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
5. Turn on filtering for the column (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>)
6. Filter for `#N/A` only. (If there are none, ignore this step and the next one.)
7. Delete all the `#N/A` rows
8. Delete columns `C`,`D`,`F`,`G`
9. Highlight the data
10. Copy the data (*excluding* headers) from `Sheet1` of Workbook 1 (the current workbook)
11. Right-click in cell `A2` of `Sheet2` and select `Insert Copied Cells`
12. Make sure `Shift cells down` is selected, the press `OK`
13. Select all the data and remove the duplicates via `Data`→`Data Tools`→`Remove Duplicates`. (Make sure only column `ID` is checked.)
14. Sort by column `ID`

The best solution, of course, is to automate these steps. This is what the following VBA code does.

Copy-paste this code into a standard module in Workbook 1:

```vb
'============================================================================================
' Module     : a standard module in Workbook 1
' Version    : 0.1.1
' Part       : 1 of 1
' References : N/A
' Source     : https://superuser.com/a/1331855/763880
'============================================================================================
Option Explicit

Public Sub CrossCompareSheets()

  Const s_CompareToWorkbook  As String = "Workbook 2.xlsx"
  Const s_CompareToSheet     As String = "Sheet1"
  Const s_CompareToTopLeft   As String = "A1"
  Const s_CompareToExtraCols As String = "C,D,F"
  Const s_SourceSheet        As String = "Sheet1"
  Const s_SourceTopLeft      As String = "A1"
  Const n_SourceMatchColumn  As Long = 2
  Const s_ResultSheet        As String = "Sheet2"
  Const s_ResultTopLeft      As String = "A1"
  Const n_ResultMatchColumn  As Long = 2
  Const n_ResultUniqueColumn As Long = 1
  Const n_ResultSortColumn   As Long = 1

  Dim wkstCompareTo  As Worksheet: Set wkstCompareTo = Workbooks(s_CompareToWorkbook).Worksheets(s_CompareToSheet)
  Dim rngCompareTo As Range: Set rngCompareTo = wkstCompareTo.Range(s_CompareToTopLeft).CurrentRegion
  Dim wkstSource  As Worksheet: Set wkstSource = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(s_SourceSheet)
  Dim rngSource As Range: Set rngSource = wkstSource.Range(s_SourceTopLeft).CurrentRegion
  Dim wkstResult  As Worksheet: Set wkstResult = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(s_ResultSheet)
  Dim rngResult As Range
  Dim celResultTopLeft As Range: Set celResultTopLeft = wkstResult.Range(s_ResultTopLeft)

  wkstResult.UsedRange.Clear
  rngCompareTo.Copy Destination:=wkstResult.Range(s_ResultTopLeft)
  Set rngResult = celResultTopLeft.CurrentRegion
  With rngResult.Resize(ColumnSize:=1).Offset(ColumnOffset:=rngResult.Columns.Count)
    .FormulaR1C1 = Replace(Replace(Replace( _
      "=MATCH(RC{a},{Sheet}!C{b},0)" _
      , "{a}", n_ResultMatchColumn), "{Sheet}", s_SourceSheet), "{b}", n_SourceMatchColumn)
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  End With
  Set rngResult = celResultTopLeft.CurrentRegion
  rngResult.AutoFilter Field:=rngResult.Columns.Count, Criteria1:="#N/A"
  rngResult.Offset(RowOffset:=1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
  rngResult.AutoFilter
  Dim colsToBeDeleted As Range
  Set colsToBeDeleted = rngResult.Resize(ColumnSize:=1).Offset(ColumnOffset:=rngResult.Columns.Count - 1).EntireColumn
  Dim varColumn As Variant
  For Each varColumn In Split(s_CompareToExtraCols, ",")
    Set colsToBeDeleted = Union(colsToBeDeleted, wkstResult.Range(varColumn & ":" & varColumn))
  Next varColumn
  colsToBeDeleted.Delete
  Set rngResult = celResultTopLeft.CurrentRegion
  rngSource.Offset(RowOffset:=1).Copy Destination:=celResultTopLeft.Offset(RowOffset:=rngResult.Rows.Count)
  Set rngResult = celResultTopLeft.CurrentRegion
  rngResult.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=n_ResultUniqueColumn, Header:=xlYes
  Set rngResult = celResultTopLeft.CurrentRegion
  With wkstResult.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=rngResult.Columns(n_ResultSortColumn)
    .SetRange rngResult
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
  End With

End Sub
```

**Notes:**

You can change the constants at the top to cater for different columns and file names and the code will automatically adjust.

Comment: I appreciate this but VBA in not feasible in my case. The data, columns and file names I'm comparing are constantly changing. It may be long and tedious, but it'll still be infinitely faster than manual comparison. Hope you can help me out.

Comment: @WilsonLiao Okie, dokie. I'll update my answer. Just so you know, I *have* set up the VBA in such a way that you could easily change the columns and file names at the top and the code will then work with the new values, It will still be quicker that way.

Comment: Ah I see. I've 0 knowledge on VBA so I'll need time to experiment with this. I'd still appreciate the non-VBA method as I still need to use it in the short term. Thanks!

Comment: @WilsonLiao OK. Got the manual steps all sorted out (I hope ;-) ) and uploaded.

Comment: If I want the new updated info highlighted in the new table, how do I do that?

Comment: @WilsonLiao Dang. I was going to work that out and add it. I've got it sorted out now. Even more steps! I'll update the answer now with the manual steps, but the code update will have to wait 'til tomorrow, EDIT: Done. The manual steps will now highlight the new updated info.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT reread question, and updated with my understanding of the problem...

Second edit where I got mixed up between sheet 1&2

To find the data that need to go in a new sheet because it only exists in sheet 1...

```
=match(a1, sheet2!a:a,0).
```

Filter for #na.

To update data in sheet 1, add a column to the right of the data a bit like this;

```
=Iferror(Index(sheet2!d:d,match(a1, sheet2!a:a,0)),D1)
```

Copy this down on a spare column in sheet 1, then copy and paste as values of the original D1 column.

Another piont; if the Id's are not consistent between the sheets (can't be used for matching) create a 'helper column' concatenate name & code, or whatever can be used to compare the 2 sheets correctly.

(If IDs can't be used to match, I would also start asking lots of questions about the data, but that's outside the scope of the question)

Comment: This will include data that isn't in the original list. I'm updating current information only in workbook 1 and ignoring all other information. I.E Sam will not be highlighted at all despite not being in the list of workbook 1. But Max's missing data will be highlighted as he is in the list in workbook 1. Is there a way I can filter this out?

Comment: @WilsonLiao Sniped!

Comment: Unfortunately your interpretation of the problem doesn't count - only the OP's does ;-) Your first formula is a promising start - it excludes all the duplicates. But when/if you get the second formula working properly (and that also entails modifying the first one), it cannot guarantee to correctly capture all the missing data as it only grabs the first one. So sometimes it will grab less and sometimes it will grab the same data more than once. The only time it will be correct if there's exact one "missing" name in Workbook 2 corresponding to exactly one name in Workbook 1.

Comment: @robin my interpretation was mentioned, because I wasn't sure I had it right, it's a bit hard to correct solve back mis-interpreted problem... which seems to have happened :-D  And your next points are excellent - I mixed up sheet 1 & 2.

Answer (score -1):

*I would like to suggest the most easiest method to compare and create unique list.*

**Follow these steps:**

- Copy data from both Workbooks into a blank sheet.
- Select Entire data.
- On Home Tab click Sort & Filter.
- Sort the data in ascending order on ID.
- Again select entire data.
- Go to Data Tab & click Remove Duplicate.
- Select ID column to find & remove duplicates.

*You find your data like shown below:*

```
ID           Name      Code
futa-123456  Max        0a
futa-123457  Max        0a
futa-123458  Max        0a
futb-ms8793  John       SX
futb-xy5543  Sam        Sx
futg-890153  May        gH
futg-890154  May        GH
```

**N.B.**

- The above shown method is suitable for small database.
- You can record whole process as Macro to work faster.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this solution doesn't work. It includes `Sam` in the result, whom the OP has spelled out very clearly is to be excluded.

Comment: Since SAM is unique record in Sheet 2 so that logically it will appear after compare both sheets for unique records. Since OP has simply copy & pasted values & OP has missed it to include in the list.